# Not able to login into /devportal and /publisher after upgrading APIM to 3.1.0 from 2.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

#### Description:

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ssoConsentServiceFactoryBean' after upgrading APIM to 3.1.0 from 2.6.0. Because of that not able to login into /devportal and /publisher

> ```sh
> [2020-05-21 20:11:32,122] ERROR - [/oauth2] Servlet.init() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] threw exception
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointUtilBean' defined in URL [file:/C:/CETANA/tools/21-05-2020/wso2am-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ssoConsentServiceFactoryBean' while setting bean property 'SSOConsentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssoConsentServiceFactoryBean' defined in URL [file:/C:/CETANA/tools/21-05-2020/wso2am-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:151) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:74) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:83) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:303) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:209) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:255) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:206) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:175) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:140) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:783) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:407) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:183) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:371) [org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.35.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:170) [org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.35.jar:?]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50) [org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence_4.7.35.jar:?]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssoConsentServiceFactoryBean' defined in URL [file:/C:/CETANA/tools/21-05-2020/wso2am-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     ... 92 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.getOSGiService(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:369) ~[org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.factory.SSOConsentServiceFactory.createInstance(SSOConsentServiceFactory.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.factory.SSOConsentServiceFactory.createInstance(SSOConsentServiceFactory.java:29) ~[classes/:?]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     ... 92 more
> [2020-05-21 20:11:32,128] ERROR - [/oauth2] Servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in web application [/oauth2] threw load() exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>     at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.getOSGiService(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:369) ~[org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.factory.SSOConsentServiceFactory.createInstance(SSOConsentServiceFactory.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.factory.SSOConsentServiceFactory.createInstance(SSOConsentServiceFactory.java:29) ~[classes/:?]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:151) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:74) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:83) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134) ~[tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089) ~[tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983) ~[tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:303) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:209) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.6.0.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:255) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:206) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:175) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:140) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42) [org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer_4.10.1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:783) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:407) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:183) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:2.1.7-wso2v147]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:371) [org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.35.jar:?]
>     at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:170) [org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer_4.7.35.jar:?]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
> ```

#### Steps to reproduce:

Getting above we start APIM after upgrading from 2.6.0 to 3.1.0

#### Environment details (with versions):

- OS: Windows
- Client:
- Env (Docker/K8s):

---

Comment: How did you migrate?

Comment: I followed the steps which are provided in the following page https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/upgrading-from-260-to-310/

Comment: are you using a WUM Updated distribution or vanilla distribution?

Comment: API Manager 3.1.0 is WUM updated distribution only. https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/3.1.0/wso2am-3.1.0.zip

Comment: Issue got resloved. This because upgradation scripts doesn't  support postgres 9.5